# A * path finding in Unity grid for 3d game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, navigation, a-star

I am working on a school project and I trying to understand how to script my own path finding system using A * search for my 3D game.

All the tutorials I have found are for mostly tile based games and use a 2d grid to store the nodes.
Is it right to use a grid for a 3d game? Any tips on how to make this grid?

Comment: This is a very broad question. This site is best suited for questions that already have attempted (but failed) solutions. This question will invite opinionated and subjective answers. Make an attempt, and once you are stuck on a technical detail, post on this site.

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Do you know how A* for 2D works? If you understood A* pathfinding on a 2D grid there shouldnt be much problems to extend it to 3D. In 2D you check all neighbours of a node (left, right, forward, backwards [and optional diagonal neighbours]). For 3D pathfinding you also have to consider the neighbours that are above and below a node (and the respective diagonals if needed). Note that the needed memory to check these paths is pretty big. What exactly is your 3D game? Are you sure you cant use a 2D grid on it? Is A* required for your project (maybe just use NavMesh)?

Answer (score 2):

Albeit fruitless to answer this, but

It's a good idea to have a grid type as a 2d array, since it's more intuitive. Then store each node object in the array.

Sorry I can't put this in the comments, I don't have enough points yet.